Blazor webassembly deploy to Github Pages not working
Deploying a simple Blazor web assembly app on .NET 8.0 (landing site) to Github pages is not working. The sample project can be found here: https://github.com/vcarlucci/Hiptoken
The deployment (Github Actions) runs successfully, but when I would like to visit the page it shows me the error 404, nothing found..
Github pages settings:


Finally I have found the issue. In the github actions .yaml I have defined the output branch to 'gh-pages'. But in the pages settings I have still referenced the 'main' branch, thats why it showed always 404 file not found. So I have changed that to 'gh-pages' and now it works.

I had a look at GitHub, you seem to be missing the <base href="/" /> line in index.html.
So the sed command in the yaml file has nothing to do.

Although I'm a little surprised that this produces a 404 .

Hey Henk, thank you very much for your contribution! Oops during testing seems I have unfortunately deleted the  '', your are absolutely right. I have added the line now in the code. But this is not helping, still 404 is coming.. I was thinking that Blazor webassembly is designed especially for such simple scenarios :(
